# Multi channel mulriorganisation hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am doing an electronic health record Hyperledger fabric network. Suppose my network has two hospitals and these hospitals need to share information like patient info etc with each other and register on the ledger. I have created three channel channel1 having peers of hospital1 and channel2 having peers of hospital2 and another channel that having peers of both organization. So that information like employees details etc won't be save on another organisations peers. Is my setup correct or do I need to make changes? and how can I share patient records to hospital2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the technical aspect, you are right. Only the channel 3 will provide a common "data sharing". 
Under the architecture aspect, what would be the purpose of the channels 1 and 2? The data will be written and read by only 1 organisation (1 hospital). So a more "classical" database would do the job.

If you want to share patient data between both hospitals, you will need to install a chaincode on all the peers of channel 3, then instantiate it. In this chaincode, you should have an invoke function, which put new patient key/value in the ledger.

Comment: Yes, I know it's irrelevant to use blockchain here, but is it possible to read patient info from the channel1 by chaincodes on the common channel. I am doing it just to become proficient in Hyperledger fabric.

Comment: Yes it is possible to invoke a chaincode of another channel from inside a chaincode. It will be a query transaction (no invoke transaction is possible). So you can read data of channel 1 from a transaction of the common channel, but only if the transaction caller has access to channel1.
    "InvokeChaincode(chaincodeName string, args [][]byte, channel string) pb.Response"

Comment: // InvokeChaincode locally calls the specified chaincode `Invoke` using the
// same transaction context; that is, chaincode calling chaincode doesn't
// create a new transaction message.

Comment: // If the called chaincode is on the same channel, it simply adds the called
// chaincode read set and write set to the calling transaction.
// If the called chaincode is on a different channel,
// only the Response is returned to the calling chaincode; any PutState calls
// from the called chaincode will not have any effect on the ledger; that is,
// the called chaincode on a different channel will not have its read set
// and write set applied to the transaction.

Comment: Only the calling chaincode's
// read set and write set will be applied to the transaction. Effectively
// the called chaincode on a different channel is a `Query`, which does not
// participate in state validation checks in subsequent commit phase.
// If `channel` is empty, the caller's channel is assumed.